# searching for unique usernames in firebase with unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to find if a username exists in the realtime database on firebase using unity c#

```cs
private IEnumerator CheckUsernameExists ( string _username)
{
    var Usernames = DBreference.RootReference.getChild("usernames");
        
    Usernames.orderByChild("username").equalTo(_username);
    yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => Usernames.IsCompleted);
    if (Usernames == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Search if the user is valid or search for a used name so a new user can register, akin to how email services tell you a user is taken?

Comment: I want to do unique usernames on unity with firebase.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo